# access profile2 fields values

Tags: 7, theming, users

How can I access fields values inside *profile2* main profile? Only on edit main profile page? I try to hide a field on profile2 edit page based on another value. Code is from my *template.php*

```
function my_theme_form_profile2_edit_main_form_alter
```

and then calling

```
global $user;
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'main');
$checkbox1 = $profile->field_checkbox_admin1['und'][0]['value'];
```

The problem is that profile variable is not accessible if all of the fields in profile are empty. dpm($profile) shows nothing and I get undefined variable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the  variable already before using it

```
$profile ="";
global $user;
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'main');
$checkbox1 = isseet($profile->field_checkbox_admin1['und'][0]['value']) ?      $profile->field_checkbox_admin1['und'][0]['value'] : "";
```

That is nature the profile 2 module, it doesn't create any entry for any field in the database untill it is not assigned any value actually. So it returns nothing if it is empty.

Hope it will help

Comment: There is no point in declaring the $profile variable before the call the profile2_load_by_user. It will be overwritten no matter what. What is missing is a test to see what was returned after the call and before making assumptions on how to use it.

Comment: @J.Reynolds How do you otherwise propose to check a value of a field inside an empty profile2 profile? I am hiding a field based on a field in same profile on same profile page. I need to get to the value first to be able to compare. If empty then hide field.

Comment: @loparr If you are checking values on the profile page, then you are better off just inspecting $form and $form_state. You say you want to hide a field on profile2 edit page based on another value. Is this 'another value' present as a field value on the same profile page? If so $form and $form_state is what you are looking at.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Defining $profile was just to avoid undefined variable error if you are using it further. Otherwise we can have many options to get the data. Also the options proposed by you is also good.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Yes, I want to control visibility of fields based on values of checkbox in the same form - so values are 0 or 1. So you say there is no need to load profile? Looking at dpm($form) I could see there are my fields but how to access boolean data? devel shows ['profile_main']['field_checkbox_admin1']['und']['#value_key']. Should I do something like $check = ['profile_main']['field_checkbox_admin1']['und']['#value_key']? Thank you

Comment: @J.Reynolds I did dsm the $form-state and found that getting to my field value should be $xxx = $form_state['profiles']['main']->field_checkbox_admin1['und'][0]['value']; Now it is getting values without need to load user profile, which is good. Thank you for guidance. If you want please write an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @J.Reynolds after some testing I found out that I have to add a check if profile exists anyway, because the field value is not accessible. The  I am confused. $form_state['profiles']['main'] object does not contain any values if this is a new user.

Comment: @loparr Just work with the values that are in the $form variable, ie. $form['profile_main']['field_YOURFIELD']. For a new user, $form_state will not yet contain a profile object, and $form_state is used for validation, submission and multi-step forms. Back to your original question, you want to hide a field dependent on another. Look at this [Drupal 7 FAPI's #states: A Great New UI Improvement For Forms](http://randyfay.com/states). There are lots of articles and videos tutorials. If you want to for example hide or show a field when a user selects a specific radio button, then this is for you.